# typedef vector size_type in header file

Tags: c++, header, typedef

I'm using Visual Studio (not sure if this is relevant here), I want to define a typedef for `vector<int>::size_type` in a header file.

This is my header:

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include "pch.h"
#include <vector>

typedef int myint;
typedef vector<int>::size_type vi_sz;

#endif //UTILS_H
```

If I try to build it then I get the following errors:

```
...\utils.h(8): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
...\utils.h(8): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
...\utils.h(8): error C2039: 'size_type': is not a member of '`global namespace''
```

If I move `typedef vector<int>::size_type vi_sz;` to source file then everything is OK. Note that I don't need to do that with `typedef int myint;`

Is there a way to define that kind of typedef in header to avoid having to define it for every source file or is this bad practice in some way?

Comment: Have you tried `std::vector<int>::size_type`?

Comment: That was the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I try to build it then I get the following errors:

Note that here:

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include "pch.h"
#include <vector>

typedef int myint;
typedef vector<int>::size_type vi_sz;

#endif //UTILS_H
```

You don't have `using namespace std;` ([as especially should be the case in header files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452738/2754173)) and yet you write `vector<int>::size_type` instead of `std::vector<int>::size_type`. Hence the name cannot be resolved.

> If I move `typedef vector<int>::size_type vi_sz;` to source file then
>   everything is OK

This compiles when in the .cpp file as you probably have a `using namespace std;` prior to `typedef vector<int>::size_type vi_sz;` in there, and so the name is resolved. In short, **just leave it in your header file like this: `typedef std::vector<int>::size_type vi_sz;`**

Answer (score 1):

It is like you are missing `std` namespace. You can do following.

1. `using namespace std;`
2. `std::vector<int>::size_type`

Try either, will resolve your issues.